# Time reporting app

Tags: time-tracking

I'm looking for a good time reporting app that possibly could be combined with 
several external partners.

Say I have project A I want to report on. Now I want my client to see all time invested in project A, even "spare time" as lunch, or time of.

I would configure time as work or free and connect it with a project. This project I can invite external partners to which can read all my reports on that project. So client A can read all reports from project A. Client B can read all reports from project B.

It would also be nice if you could make up a plan so they know what to expect.

To me this seem so basic, but I can not find any that suites my needs.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe but i'm mostly interested in time tracking used by freelancers with those specific needs we often have. With several external clients and being able to share some time with client A and some time with client B. It must be a very common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Toggl](https://toggl.com/pricing). I think it might suit most of your needs.

- there is a free tier so you can check if it works for you
- it's $5 per month for the pro account
- it works on all major platforms (iOS, Android, OS X, Windows, web)
- it's very simple to start a project and add time entries
- you can have multiple clients and projects
- it has straightforward report create and export capability
- the pro version lets you set various client rates
- the pro version lets you share an auto updated report to your client

I used it as a freelancer and in a team of 5 on a bigger project. As long as you get the team to track time, reporting to the client is simple as a single click.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an app only, it's an online service that offers apps for different platforms: Have a look at [Freshbooks](https://www.freshbooks.com/).

It will let you add clients and as many projects as you want for each clients. You can choose different currency for each client and also have many logins for one single client (eg. for members of their own team).

Clients and collaborators can get access to your online time sheets and other reports. Member areas are private. You can also see who logged in and a feed of activity.

For you own team, it's possible to download apps with timers that are linked to each clients and projects; you can use the apps with specific tasks and the online time sheet will get updated automatically. You can also add a note within the timer app about what you're working on and the note will be added to the time sheet as well.

There's some free versions for the time tracking app but you can also  purchase other apps at low cost. Or build your own. The default one works perfectly fine.

It's also possible to have different price for each task or project. Prices can be flat per/project or per/hour or per/task.

You can also add/upload expenses related to a project. Clients will be able to see these expenses.

There's a simple "ticket/dispute" system as well.

Finally, when a project is completed, you can use Freshbooks to invoice your client; it will let you calculate and prepare automatically a detailed invoice with all the time and task entries, and calculate the total for you. Clients will be able to pay online and you can use different payment gateway (WePay, Paypal, Stripe, etc.) It creates an invoice in PDF file and clients can see all their previous invoices online in their member areas. You can send the invoice by email or snail mail; Freshbooks will mail for you.

Their customer support is also amazing.

---

**Time Tracking details:**

https://www.freshbooks.com/timesheets-and-time-tracking

**Reports:**

https://www.freshbooks.com/financial-reporting

**Add-ons:**

https://www.freshbooks.com/addons

---

<sup>PS: I use it for many years, it's certainly one of the biggest time saver to manage projects. I've tried a few timers and this one has always been the easiest to use for both clients and my team, and the timer app is great.</sup>

Comment: I also use Freshbooks, however I use Toggl for time tracking - it integrates with Freshbooks automatically if you have a paid account, and is solely for time tracking, and managing a team of freelancers. So I'd consider looking at both software and the potential integration.

Answer (score 0):

[timedoctor.com](https://www.timedoctor.com/) and [worksnaps.net](http://www.worksnaps.net/www/) are good for time tracking. Both give a desktop time tracker to be installed on desktop for the people who work on a project with screenshot taking capability so that each hour worked is each hour paid. They are similar to [odesk.com](http://odesk.com) now [upwork.om](http://upwork.com) time tracker.

However the responsibility to evaluate the the performance still is yours when your employees or contractors do the work.

These time trackers can then connect with apps like [freshbooks.com](http://freshbooks.com) that are for project management and bookkeeping.

Comment: @canadian-luke i did :) thanks!

Comment: Can you add the cost as well?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Hubstaff](https://hubstaff.com) 
I found them to be very reasonable for it's price and customer support quite satisfactory too.

Following are some of it's key features:

- Accurate time tracking against multiple organizations, projects and tasks.
- Multi-platform support for Web, mobile (iPhone app), Windows, Mac & Linux.
- Integrates with over 30 other task/project management tools (and growing) including Trello, Asana, QuickBooks and Basecamp.
- Simple and quick invoicing with accessible timesheets.
- Online dashboard and reports.

You can try their free [iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id971894122?pt=2184201&ct=se1&mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **http://www.hivedesk.com** for **Time Tracking and Task Management** software that makes remote team collaboration easier. It is a powerful and simple-to-use project management tool to manage your team and tasks.

Top Features:

•   Time tracking software with screenshots

•   Project and task management

•   Review your remote workers’ logged time and productivity.

•   View and generate reports and graphs of their activity.

•   Remote workers have peace of mind knowing that productivity and time are not tracked unless they are checked into a project.

Comment: Are you associated with this website in any way?